# MySQL IF/Else statement results as columns

Tags: mysql, sql

Can i write a query for the following condition?

```
if (online_member == 0) {
    offline_member = offline_member + 1;
} else {
   online_member = online_member + 1;
}
```

My Query:

```
SELECT `name`, 
        SUM(IF(online_member =0, 1, 0)) AS offline_member, 
        SUM(IF(online_member =1, 1, 0)) AS online_member 
FROM members
```

is there any better way to write the above query?

Comment: You can use [`CASE...END`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case) construct.  Not sure whether it's better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simplify the MySQL syntax to:

```
SELECT `name`, 
        SUM(online_member = 0) AS offline_member, 
        SUM(online_member = 1) AS online_member 
FROM members
GROUP BY name;
```

I added the `group by name` because that would seem to be the intention if you are including `name` in the `select`.  If you just wanted counts of online and offline members, overall, using ANSI syntax:

```
SELECT sum(case when online_member = 0 then 1 else 0 end) as offline_member,
       sum(case when online_member = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as online_member
FROM members;
```

To be honest, the `if` is MySQL specific syntax.  So I the first version is "better" in the sense that it is more concise.  The second version is "better" in the sense that it is standard.  But, I would also emphasize that nothing is wrong with using `if` in MySQL.